# xcode8 stroyboard can‘t updata when choose device

Tags: ios, autolayout

[image]

When I change the device to iPhone7 Plus, storyboard can't update frame by itself. When I back to iphone 7, the frame is iphone7 Plus. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Pls add what constraints you gives to these components

Comment: view height 260 top 0 left 0 right 0,
green is imagview on the view ,top 0 left 0 ,right 0,bottom 0

Comment: I use another Mac, on that computer, this question don't happen

Comment: Try to relaunch your x-code and try again bcz constraints are perfect.

Comment: Check for the simulator size, is it fixed or freeform. Make it Inferred, then on device change, view frames will update.